# Change style of data-element depending on what class it currently has?

Tags: javascript, jquery

What I'm trying to do is when the slider control dot with data-slide-to="1" has the class "active" then I want to set .slider-overlay a's background color to gold. This is what I've tried but it doesn't work.

```
$(document).ready(function(){

$('.active[data-slide-to="1"]') {
    $('.slider-overlay a').css('background', 'gold')
}

});
```

html for slider

```
<div class="jumbotron">
    <div id="carouselExampleIndicators" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
    <ol class="carousel-indicators">
      <li data-target="#carouselExampleIndicators" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
      <li data-target="#carouselExampleIndicators" data-slide-to="1"></li>
    </ol>
    <div class="carousel-inner" role="listbox">
      <!-- Slide One - Set the background image for this slide in the line below -->
      <div class="carousel-item slide-cc active" style="background: #111">
        <div class="carousel-caption d-none d-md-block">
                </div>
      </div>
      <!-- Slide Two - Set the background image for this slide in the line below -->
      <div class="carousel-item slide-2waytray" style="background: #444">
        <div class="carousel-caption d-none d-md-block">
                </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <a class="carousel-control-prev" href="#carouselExampleIndicators" role="button" data-slide="prev">
      <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
      <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
    </a>
    <a class="carousel-control-next" href="#carouselExampleIndicators" role="button" data-slide="next">
      <span class="carousel-control-next-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
      <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
    </a>
  </div>

    <div class="slider-overlay">
    <h1>Welcome!</h1>
    <a href="" title="Get Started">Get Started</a>
    </div>

</div>
```

.slider-overlay a stays on the page at all times, I just want to change the color of it's background depending on which slide is active.

Here is a jsfiddle https://jsfiddle.net/tpbbuqjh/2/

Comment: Can you include HTML at Question? Is `.slider-overlay a` a child node or sibling of `.active[data-slide-to="1"]`?

Comment: I just added it, sorry

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`MutationObserver`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MutationObserver) to observer changes to element attributes, perform task at the mutation notification

```js
let observer = new MutationObserver(function(mutations) {
  mutations.forEach(function(mutation) {
    if (mutation.target.className === "active") {
      $(".slider-overlay a").css("background", "gold");
      return false
    }
  })
});

let target = $("li[data-slide-to='1']")[0];

let config = {attributeFilter:["class"]};

observer.observe(target, config);

setTimeout(function() {
  target.className = "active"
}, 5000)
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="jumbotron">
  <div id="carouselExampleIndicators" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
    <ol class="carousel-indicators">
      <li data-target="#carouselExampleIndicators" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
      <li data-target="#carouselExampleIndicators" data-slide-to="1"></li>
      <li data-target="#carouselExampleIndicators" data-slide-to="2"></li>
    </ol>
    <div class="carousel-inner" role="listbox">
      <!-- Slide One - Set the background image for this slide in the line below -->
      <div class="carousel-item slide-cc active" style="background: #111">
        <div class="carousel-caption d-none d-md-block">
        </div>
      </div>
      <!-- Slide Two - Set the background image for this slide in the line below -->
      <div class="carousel-item slide-2waytray" style="background: #444">
        <div class="carousel-caption d-none d-md-block">
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <a class="carousel-control-prev" href="#carouselExampleIndicators" role="button" data-slide="prev">
      <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
      <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
    </a>
    <a class="carousel-control-next" href="#carouselExampleIndicators" role="button" data-slide="next">
      <span class="carousel-control-next-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
      <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
    </a>
  </div>

  <div class="slider-overlay">
    <h1>Welcome!</h1>
    <a href="" title="Get Started">Get Started</a>
  </div>

</div>
```

Comment: Oh that does work but I have no idea what any of it means! It stays gold after going back to the first slide though. How would I have it change so that it matches the current slide if there are 3-4 different ones?

Comment: What do you mean by "the current slide"?

Comment: Well the image slider starts out with an image that has orange on it. When the next slide loads it has yellow in it and this code changes the button to yellow, which matches, but when the slide goes back to the orange one the button stays yellow. It would have to match the background color with the color of the slide that is active.

Comment: Where are the list of colors stored? The original question is specific to a single element, yes?

Comment: For this example, just orange and gold. It makes sense that if it changes to gold on slide #2 that it should go back to what it originally was when the original slide comes back up.

Comment: You can use the same pattern at Answer to attach a `MutationObserver` to other elements

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't understand most of this jquery. Would I just copy and paste this a second time and change the variables?

Comment: Yes, you could use the same pattern and adjust variable identifiers

Comment: I'm guessing this isn't the way to do it because it isn't working https://pastebin.com/jepvq6RT

Comment: You are close, remove `2` at `if (mutation.target2.className === "active") {`

Comment: Awesome! I changed the instances of target that were variables to targetOne and targetTwo instead so I didn't mix them up with the one that is an object.

Answer (score 0):

```js
$(document).ready(function(){

if($('.active').attr('data-slide-to')=="1") {
    $('body').css('background', 'gold')
}

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="active" data-slide-to="1"></div>
```

Comment: This doesn't work. I think it has something to do with the page loading with the .active being on data-slide-to="0" and not being matched with 1 until the slide changes. This works if I put it into jfiddle with .active hard coded to data-slide-to="1".